# How does this recursive C code work?

Tags: c, recursion

There are lots of recursion questions and I basically understand some simple recursion algorithm such as sum of array elements. However, my friend gave me this code which reverses an array:

```
void r(int a[], int s)
{
     if(s <=2 ) return;
     int t = a[0];
     a[0] = a[s-1];
     a[s-1] = t;

     r(&a[1], s-2); //  this line confused me, why &a[1]
}
```

I know how to reverse an array using a normal for loop. But this code really confused me about recursion.

Can anyone explain the above line of code?

Comment: IMHO the line `if(s <=2 ) return;` should be `if(s < 2 ) return;`

Comment: @wildplasser You're absolutely right; see analysis in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is equvalent to

```
void r(int *arr, size_t len)
{
     for ( ; len >= 2; arr+=1,len-=2 ) {
       int t = arr[0];
       arr[0] = arr[len-1];
       arr[len-1] = t;
       }

}
```

, where the recursive call is replaced by the loop. Ihe "increment" part of the loop (`arr+=1,len-=2`) is exactly the same as the parameters for the recursive call; the end condition (`len >= 2`) is equivalent to the recursion stopper (which was wrong in the original).

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind this algorithm is at each step:

-: to swap the last `a[s-1]` and first `a[0]` elements of the array:

```
    int t = a[0];
    a[0] = a[s-1];
    a[s-1] = t;
```

-: and to swap the middle recursively:

```
    r(&a[1], s-2);
```

To understand the syntax, keep in mind that `&a[n]` is address of the `n+1`th element of the given array. If you have `int *b = &a[1]`, then `b[0] == a[1]`, `b[1] == a[2]`, etc.

So:

- `&a[1]` refers to an array starting at the second element of array `a`.
- `s - 2` means that the length of the array you pass recursively is shorter by 2 elements.

If you have an array `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]`, here's what happens as the recursion progresses:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10] // r(&a[0], 10)
10 [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] 1 //   r(&a[1], 8
10 9 [3 4 5 6 7 8] 2 1 //     r(&(&a[1])[1], 6)
10 9 8 [4 5 6 7] 3 2 1 //       r(&(&(&a[1])[1])[1], 4)
10 9 8 7 [5 6] 4 3 2 1 //         r(&(&(&(&a[1])[1])[1])[1], 2)
```

Cool thing is that this analysis shows us that the terminating condtion `s <= 2` is wrong: the innermost 2 elements in an even-sized array will never get swapped. It should be changed to `s < 2`.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Simplified</strike> Crazy walk trough;

```
void reverse(int a[], int s)
{
    int temp;              /* temporary value */

    if (s <= 2) return;    /* trigger done */

    t        = a[0];       /* temp = first index of a */
    a[0]     = a[s - 1];   /* a[0] = a[end - 1] (end including \0) */
    a[s - 1] = t;          /* a[end - 1] = temp */

    r(&a[1], s - 2);       /* pass address of a[1] and end - 2 */
}
```

---

Given the char array `"ABCDEFG"`

Simplified memory table could be:

```
Address  Value
      7      A
      8      B
      9      C
      a      D
      b      E
      c      F
      d      G

/* Or as used here: */

789abcd <- Simplified memory address
ABCDEFG
```

We get; `main()` calls `reverse(ABCDEFG, 7)`

<sup>List 1</sup>

- Address ref. to `A` are pushed on to the stack (A{BCDEFG})
- 7 are pushed on to the stack
- return address for caller is pushed onto the stack
- etc.
- function called

And something like

```
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

reverse(ABCDEFG, 7); # Push to STACK 0xB (As List 1)
#====================================================
789abcd <- Memory address.
ABCDEFG <- Values.
0123456 <- Indexes for a in recursion 1.

if (7 <= 2) return;
temp = A
               +     .
a[0] = a[6] => ABCDEFG = GBCDEFG
                     +
a[6] = temp => GBCDEFG = GBCDEFA
```

---

```
reverse(BCDEFA, 5); # Push to STACK 0xC (As in List 1)
#====================================================
 7 89abcd <- Memory addresses.
[G]BCDEFA <- Values
   012345 <- Indexes for a in recursion 2.

if (5 <= 2) return;
temp = B
               +   .
a[0] = a[4] => BCDEFA = FCDEFA
                   +
a[4] = temp => FCDEFA = FCDEBA
```

---

```
reverse(CDEBA, 3); # Push to STACK 0xD (As in List 1)
#====================================================
 78 9abcd <- Memory addresses.
[GF]CDEBA <- Values.
    01234 <- indexes for a in recursion 3.

if (3 <= 2) return;
temp = C
               + .
a[0] = a[2] => CDEBA = EDEBA
                 +
a[2] = temp => EDEBA = EDCBA
```

---

```
reverse(DCBA, 1); # Push to STACK 0xE (As in List 1)
#====================================================
 789 abcd <- Memory addresses.
[GFE]DCBA <- Values.
     0123 <- Indexes for a in recursion 4.
if (1 <= 2) return; YES!
```

---

```
#:::: roll back stack ::::

Pop STACK 0xE
Pop STACK 0xD
Pop STACK 0xC
Pop STACK 0xB
We are back in main() and memory region 789abcd has 
been altered from ABCDEFG to GFEDCBA.
```

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to realize is that `a` is a pointer to the first element of the array, so `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. `&a[1]` is a pointer to the second element of the array. So if you call the function with `&a[1]` as its argument, it works on the subarray that starts with the second element.

Answer (score 0):

`&a[1]` is equivalent to `a + 1`, i.e. a pointer to the second element of the array. The function call reverses the "middle" `s-2` elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The function has to be called with:

- A pointer to the first element of the array. In C it can be referenced by using the name of the array.
- The size of the array.

The first 'if' checks that the array has as least two elements. Next, what the function does is to exchange the position of the first and the last element of the array.

The recursive call changes the bounds at which the next step has to work. It increments the beginning of the array by one position, and also decreases the end of the array by one position; since these two elements have been reversed in this iteration.